# Moving button pushing content

Tags: css, animation, button, transition

So I’m doing CSS, and I’ve started styling my inputs & buttons. I have a set-up where the bottom border of the button is wider, and clicking the button shortens the border and moves the button downwards, creating a pseudo-3d “push” effect. The problem is that when I press down the button, the content below it moves up. this should not happen, because (from my understanding), the bottom of the button is in the same place. I enabled an outline on the button, which does not move the whole time. Then, I thought I could push the content back, by increasing the bottom margin. This keeps the below content at the same distance when the animation ends, but it jitters around during the animation, so it is still sub-optimal.

Here’s my code (I’ve included an example of a button with and without the changing margin):

---

```css
button {
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    border-bottom:solid 3px #ccc;
    padding:4px;
    transition:border-width 0.2s ease, transform 0.2s ease, margin-bottom 0.2s ease;
    margin-bottom:4px;
    outline:solid 1px #000;
}
button:active {
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    transform:translateY(2px);
}
.margin-button:active {
    margin-bottom:6px;
}
```

```html
<p>text</p>
<p><button>button with static margin</button></p>
<p>text</p>
<p><button class="margin-button">button with changing margin</button></p>
<p>text</p>
```

---

So my question is: *How can I remove the jitter with the changing margin, or is there a completely different way I can be doing this that would work out better?*

---

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Cyoce/jknx5c66/

---

Edit:I forgot to mention this, but I’d like the bottom border—or whatever is used to recreate/simulate it—to change colors (in this case, #0af) when hovered over.

Comment: Unless I'm confused by your question, the `margin-button` class appears to have the desired effect.

Comment: @DanielWilliams I suggest you reread the question - _"keeps it at the same distance when the animation ends, but it jitters around during the animation"_.

Comment: The second button that has the `margin-button ` doesn't jitter when I click it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a box-shadow instead of a border and then animate the box-shadow and transform.

The jitter occurs because everytime the border or margin changes, it has to redraw the page, which is very inefficient.

It's better to animate properties that do not trigger a repaint (such as transform and border-box).

Here's an example:
http://codepen.io/TheDutchCoder/pen/ogdLQG

```
button {
  position: relative;

  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;

  background-color: #eee;

  transition: all 0.15s ease;

  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #ccc;
}

button:focus,
button:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #ccc;
}
```

Comment: This worked, but is there a way to make the shadow change to a different color (in this case, #0af) when hovered over? I had this originally with the border, but I can’t figure out how to change the shadow color. `box-shadow-color` doesn't work, and doing `box-shadow:#0af` or `box-shadow 100% 100% 100% #0af` haven’t seemed to have an effect.

Comment: Yeah sure, just redefine it like so: box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #0af; on hover :) I've update my codepen with the hjover as well.

Comment: Figured out the color issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Reinier Kaper suggested a good solution and explained its advantages in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28663765/2788872) pretty well.

But, if you do insist on using the `border-bottom` (or similar) attribute as the core of your transition, I know two possible workarounds that I regularly use myself:

1. make the button element floating, by applying for example `float: left`, or
2. give the button's container a fixed height.

[Working example on JSFiddle featuring both approaches.](http://jsfiddle.net/jknx5c66/4/)

---

As a site node - and only on my opinion - making your elements slow to mouse gestures should be avoided: I suggest adding a `transition-duration: 0` property to the `:active` element: http://jsfiddle.net/jknx5c66/5/